# Flutter Swipe Cards Lagging and Swiping is too slow what is the solution to make it fast?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am building a tinder and bumble like dating app in a flutter. So, I am using swipe cards and as I have to make it scrollable so when I make it scrollable then the swiping is too slow and there is so much lagging so is there any solution to get rid of it?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:swipe_cards/swipe_cards.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> _images = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594744803329-e58b31de8bf5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80",
    "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/11/17/books/review/17Salam/Salam1-superJumbo.jpg",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488426862026-3ee34a7d66df?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508214751196-bcfd4ca60f91?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488716820095-cbe80883c496?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=333&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485043433441-db091a258e5a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"
  ];

  List<SwipeItem> _swipeItems = [];
  MatchEngine? _matchEngine;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    for (int i = 0; i < _images.length; i++) {
      _swipeItems.add(SwipeItem(content: _images[i]));
    }
    _matchEngine = MatchEngine(swipeItems: _swipeItems);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Color(0xff7cc8cc),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff76c9b2),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Flutter Tinder Cards'),
      ),
      body: SwipeCards(
          matchEngine: _matchEngine!,
          onStackFinished: () {},
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              height: screenHeight,
              width: screenWidth,
              child: Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CachedNetworkImage(
                        placeholder: (context, url) =>
                            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                        height: screenHeight,
                        width: screenWidth,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        //imageUrl: imgUrls![0],
                        imageUrl: _images[0],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 23.0,
                          top: 12,
                          bottom: 12,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Poonam, 18',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: Colors.black87),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 23,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.location_on_sharp,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Surat, India',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 12, left: 23, right: 22, bottom: 8),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Personal Information',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 6,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Ex - Zerodha, Ex - Grant Thornton. I used to crunch numbers and value companies for a living, now I’m trying to build one.',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Height',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    "5'11",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Community',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Vaishnav',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Gender',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Female',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Workout',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Regularly',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      //imgUrls![1] == ''
                      Container(
                        height: 569,
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          //imageUrl: imgUrls![1],
                          imageUrl: _images[1],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 12, left: 23, right: 22, bottom: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Professional Information',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Education',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Master Degree',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Worklife',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    '',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Salary',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Above 10Lpa',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      //imgUrls![2] == ''
                      Container(
                        height: 569,
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          //imageUrl: imgUrls![2],
                          imageUrl: _images[2],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 12, left: 23, right: 22, bottom: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Social Life',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Drinking',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Never',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Smoking',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Never',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 569,
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          //imageUrl: imgUrls![3],
                          imageUrl: _images[3],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 12, left: 23, right: 22, bottom: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Others',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Zodiac Sign',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Leo',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Political inclination',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Apolitics',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    'Movies',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    'Hindi Cinema',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      //imgUrls![4] == ''
                      Container(
                        height: 569,
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          imageUrl: _images[4],
                          //imageUrl: imgUrls![4],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      //imgUrls![5] == ''
                      Container(
                        height: 569,
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          imageUrl: _images[5],
                          //imageUrl: imgUrls![5],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 80,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Here, instead of SinglechildScrollView I have also tried to use ListView and ListView.builder but the same problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the app in a emulator or a physical device? Debug mode or release?

Using debug mode all the app looks like slow and has a lot of lagging, even more when using a emulator.

Comment: I am running the app on a physical device and in debug mode.